# ssh port forwarding not working with web socket

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have a server on a remote linux machine that's listening on port `8546`, using this command `ssh -L 8546:127.0.0.1:8546 user@ip` I forward the port and it's working but not with wss. I have another rpc endpoint and using the same syntax I manage to forward traffic. How to fix?